# PHP scraping information from another URL, Blank page or E_NOTICE : type 8 -- Trying to get property of non-object

Tags: php, curl, screen-scraping, simpledom

basically I'm trying to make a small tracking plugin for my website, and I'm not sure what I am meant to put get the correct name for the element ID. I either get a blank screen or E_NOTICE : type 8 -- Trying to get property of non-object

I just want to display this

https://puu.sh/EItml/34bdb97863.png

Here was the first I tried...

```
    include('simple_html_dom.php');

    $html = file_get_html('https://www.auspost.com.au/mypost/track/#/details/63243842914091');

    echo $html->find('title', 0)->plaintext;

    $list = $html->find('div[class="event-header"]',0);

    $list_array = $list->find('a');

    for( $i = 0; $i < sizeof($list_array); $i++ ){
        echo $list_array[$i]->plaintext;
        echo "<br>";
    }

?>
```

and the second

```
    include('simple_html_dom.php');

    $html = file_get_html('https://www.auspost.com.au/mypost/track/#/details/63243842914091');

    echo $html->find('title', 0)->plaintext;
    echo $ret = $html->find('event-location', 0)->plaintext;



?>
```

I did do some research but I'm unsure as to what I need to put, sorry if this is a timewaster, I'm just new to PHP...

Here's of where its located on the URL

https://puu.sh/EItlK/671f9877ed.png

https://puu.sh/EIt9C/be30180469.png

TIA :)

Comment: Don't scrape HTML to determine this information, it's prone to errors. There's [a tracking API](https://developers.auspost.com.au/apis/shipping-and-tracking/getting-started) you can use instead.

Comment: @AlexHowansky unfortunately mate all API's have prices, I do not meet the parcel requirements for the API account otherwise that was my first option, 
The only reason why I go to this is that is has a direct link (www.auspost.com.au/mypost/track/#/details/xxxxx) & also the website has not changed in the past 2 years,
"As the Shipping and Tracking API is currently only available to Australia Post eParcel and StarTrack contract customers,"

Comment: If you're scraping this URL the first real issue is that the # sign and anything after it is not sent to the server. This is client-side stuff so it's likely rendered with Javascript afterwards, so curl isn't going to see the data you want. The browser then requests info on your behalf, but it does so with a generated recaptcha token to try and prevent exactly what you're doing I'm afraid. It looks like it can potentially be done but you'll need to follow all the js/cookie/recaptcha requests and rebuild exactly what the browser is doing.

Comment: @David Right I see, so would doing following all the js/cookie/recaptcha requests still be done by scraping?

Comment: @xtraele Yep - from the quick look I had, it looks like the process would be: 1. Scrape the /track URL; 2. Scrape the Google recaptcha js URL; 3. Using the contents of that file, scrape a POST request to the API. You can see what's happening in the Network tab of the webinspector in your browser.